# Why is ob_get_contents not working

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
hi
<?php echo ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();
```

But nothing is outputted.
If I remove the `ob_end_clean();` the output is `hi hi`. If `ob_flush()` isn't called at the end of the app, the contents are automatically flushed, again.

I need to use `ob_get_contents()` because I am going to implement a simple caching mechanism that saves the the output to a file.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you're echoing the output buffer to the output buffer. It needs to be assigned to a variable and echoed after `ob_end_clean();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** I am surprised but your example does actually work with output buffering.  I did not think that HTML between php tags would work but it does.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
Hello World
<?php 
echo "Goodbye";
$test = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); echo "output:".$test;
?>
```

This outputs `output: Hello World Goodbye`.

The problem is you are echoing ob_get_contents into the buffer.  As your question in the comments was about templating, I still think you are going about output buffering wrong.  You should push PHP variables into an HTML template, not pull an HTML template into a PHP script.  You should also look into a controller/view solution but below is a basic example.

**Templating:** For templating, a basic example could be:

```
<?php
ob_start();
...PHP LOGIC HERE...
...PHP LOGIC HERE...
...PHP LOGIC HERE...
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
<html>
<body>
<div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. having `<?php ob_start();?> hi <?php ob_flush?>` works as intended, so I don't think that's the case

Comment: @jasonszhao You are trying to capture elements in the buffer _before_ outputting. Closing PHP and putting `hi` ends the buffer before it captures it.

Comment: @Devon It is not buffering for me. Only if I contain the HTML outside the PHP tags with `if` `else` conditioning, are you sure? Without it it seems to just close PHP. I am running PHP 5.3

Comment: When I do it outside the buffer I get a read time of `0.0000140000` to `0.0000180000` when I do it per the documentation and in variables I get `0.0000120000` to `0.0000150000` average in timing. i'd like to know what the differences are.

Comment: @WASasquatch the code I put at the top worked for me.